# 耳をすます、何といみですか？what does it mean?

Tags: meaning, definitions

私は漢字ドリル本から漢字を勉強している。例文は”耳をすます”。

The sentence stands alone with no context.

Comment: Did you try a dictionary?
http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E8%80%B3%E3%82%92%E6%BE%84%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99

Comment: I used a paper one, I'll bookmark the one you linked to. :)
Thank you

Comment: It doesn't matter much in this case; but: Context is more than the surrounding sentences - a (written) sentence doesn't just float in empty space, it's always written down somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 耳をすます

It means "Listen Carefully". or "lend a discerning ear".